# Is it possible to limit work item types a user can create?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'd like to limit the types of Work Items a user can create.
For exemple, on the same project,  TEAM A can create Epics, Features, Pbis and TEAM B can only create BUG.

How ca I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. It is not possible to restrict access to work items on a type-by-type basis; if a user can create a work item, they can create *all types*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that through the process customization. You can add a new group (like DenyCreateSomeWIs) and add users to it. Then update needed work item types with rules "Restrict the transition to state":

[image]

As a result:

[image]

Check the documentation: [Apply rules to workflow states (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround for this.

1. Create a group for the people whom you do not want to be able to create a work item type.
2. On the work item rules, create a rule that makes the title read-only for members of that group.  When users are a member of that group, they will not be able to save that work item without a title.

[image]